# Select Distinct from a list of IEnumerable<T> in .NET 2.0

Tags: vb.net, ienumerable

I am trying to filter an IEnumerable object of the duplicate values, so I would like to get the distinct values from it, for example, lets say that it holds days:

monday
tuesday
wednesday
wednesday

I would like to filter it and return:

monday 
tuesday
wednesday

What is the most efficient way to do this in .net 2.0?

Comment: Can you compile with a 3.5 compiler?

Comment: no kidding, JaredPar, this is a one liner with LINQ.

Comment: JaredPar makes a good point, you can use a lot of LINQ-y syntax with a C# 3.0 compiler (VS2008, .NET 3.5) even when targetting .NET 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dictionary<object, object> list = new Dictionary<object, object>();
foreach (object o in enumerable)
    if (!list.ContainsKey(o))
    {
        // Do the actual work.
        list[o] = null;
    }
```

Dictionary will use a hash table to hold keys therefore lookup is efficient.

Sorting will be O(n log(n)) at best. A hash table with an efficient hash function often outperforms it (O(1) lookups).

Comment: Yeah, it works if you don't have any other things to do with the data, which is unlikely. If you mean iterating through the o.Keys collection once again, it's not a good idea as it doesn't preserve the order of items in the original collection and it's definitely slower.

Answer (score 1):

Make another IEnumerable.  Sort the original.  For each item in the original, if the new one doesn't contain the old one, add it.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use HashSet<T> - a HashSet doesn't allow duplicate items to be used and doesn't require a key/value pair.

Comment: Wow, that's my mistake - I didn't realize that HashSet was part of System.Core.  My mistake!