# Remove duplicates from generic list<T>

Tags: c#, generics, .net-2.0, duplicate-data

I have came with solution to remove duplicates from generic list<T> in .NET 2.0 as follows:

```
List<CaseStudy> caseStudies = CaseStudyDAO.FindCaseStudiesByDate(DateTime.Now.Date, DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1));
caseStudies.RemoveAll(
        delegate(CaseStudy c)
        {
            return caseStudies.IndexOf(c) != caseStudies.FindIndex(
                delegate(CaseStudy f) { return c.Str == f.Str; });
        });
```

My questions are:

Is there more efficient way to do this? Only .NET 2.0 solution
What is the complexity of the above solution?

Thanks,
jan2k10

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344519/select-distinct-from-a-list-of-ienumerablet-in-net-2-0

Comment: the question was about specific solution

Comment: sry, the answers on that question contained complexity and most efficient way - nearly all the things you asked for... you should maybe restate your question to only asking for the complexity of your solution

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The time complexity of RemoveAll is O(n). The time complexity of the indexing is O(n), so that's a grand total of O(n^2) time complexity.  The space complexity is, I think, O(1).

Is there a more efficient way to do it?  Yes. You can do it in O(n) time complexity provided you're willing to spend more space on it.

Comment: Plus for explaining complexity

Comment: Yes, the space complexity of RemoveAll is O(1). As Eric suggests, if you are willing to use more space, you can build a `Dictionary<T>` of the items in the list (use the item as both the key and value, or something similar). Or look for a pre-existing `Set<T>` implementation that people have built.

Answer (score 5):

Just to expand on Eric's comment about O(n) time if you're happy to use more space, I'd do something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, CaseStudy> lookup = new Dictionary<string, CaseStudy>();
foreach (CaseStudy cs in caseStudies)
{
    lookup[cs.Str] = cs;
}
caseStudies = new List<CaseStudy>(lookup.Values);
```

A couple of notes:

- This changes the value of `caseStudies` to refer to a new list. If you wanted it to be within the same `List<T>`, you could use:

  ```
  caseStudies.Clear();
  caseStudies.AddRange(lookup.Values);
  ```
- This keeps the *last* element in the list with each distinct `Str` value. That was just to make it as short as possible. If you want the *first* element, use:

  ```
  foreach (CaseStudy cs in caseStudies)
  {
      if (!lookup.ContainsKey(cs.Str))
      {
          lookup[cs.Str] = cs;
      }
  }
  ```